# Predict failed to reproduce result of multiple linear regression

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, linear-algebra, machine-learning

I would like to reproduce the result of multiple linear regression with `Predict`. In approach 1, I used matrix computation and obtained `3.2`, while in approach 2, I used `Predict` directly and obtained `4.05`.

Upon checking with other statistical software, `3.2` should be correct. May I ask why approach 2 is wrong, and how can I fix the problem?

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3};
data2 = {2, 3, 5};
data3 = {3, 5, 8};
data4 = {4, 5, 8.5};
X = {data1, data2, data3, data4};
Y = {1.2, 2.5, 3.3, 4.9};
ToBePredicted = {3, 6, 9};
```

Approach 1 - Matrix Computation - Result:`3.2` (correct)

```
X1 = ArrayFlatten[{{X, ConstantArray[{1}, 4]}}];
X1T = Transpose[X1];
β = Inverse[X1T.X1].X1T.Y;
β.Append[ToBePredicted, 1]
```

Approach 2 - `Predict` - Result:`4.05` (wrong)

```
asso = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {X, Y}];
p = Predict[asso, Method -> "LinearRegression"];
p[ToBePredicted]
```

Comment: `p2 = Predict[asso, Method -> {"LinearRegression","L2Regularization"->0}]; p2[ToBePredicted]` gives the same result as `β.Append[ToBePredicted, 1] `

Comment: as stated in [Documentation >> Predict >> Properties & Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html) : _The linear regression predictor without regularization and LinearModelFit can train equivalent models_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the suboption `"L2Regularization" -> 0` for `"LinearRegression"` in `Method` option setting gives the same result as the matrix computation in OP:

```
p2 = Predict[asso, Method -> {"LinearRegression", "L2Regularization" -> 0}];
p2[ToBePredicted]
```

> 2.8

which is the same as

```
β.Append[ToBePredicted, 1]
```

> 2.8

[Documentation >> Predict >> Properties & Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html) :

> The linear regression predictor without regularization and *LinearModelFit* can train equivalent models.